# Is there a queue pool in Rabbitmq?

Tags: php, rabbitmq, pool

I'm a newbie with Rabbitmq so sorry in advance if this is obvious. So is there a queue pool in Rabbitmq or how do I implement a queue pool in Rabbitmq, something like thread pool, which means I pre-create a pool of queue for future use ?

The reason I am asking this is because in php sample codes here, https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/php-amqp/rpc_client.php, I find the queue is created on demand and when the php process finishes the queue will be reclaimed. That seems quite inefficient in term of using queue. But is this the case ? And is queue pool the way to fix it or there is other way ?

Answer (score 0):

In that example, the queue is declared as [exclusive](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#exclusive-queues), and it will be deleted when the connection closes.

Plain queues are not deleted automatically (you have several options to delete queues automatically such as exclusive, queue TTL, auto-delete queues...)